# How to run this powershell file from php

Tags: php, powershell

I would like to send emails from php but I had issues with PHPMailer and others things I tried. I figured how to do it differently: it's working perfectly in the command line (on a centos 7 terminal) using Send-Mail, i receive the mail, the html works too, here is the command(the variables are defined):

```
Send-MailMessage -To $To -From $From -SmtpServer $Smtpserver -Port "25" -Subject $Subject -Body $Message -BodyAsHtml -Encoding $encoding
```

It also works when I do it in the php interactive shell

```
exec('pwsh /data/web/html/myScript.ps');
```

But when I load the php web page with the exec() command on my browser, nothing happend, I don't receive the mail or get any error.

I don't know if the error comes from powershell or php, ask if more info is needed. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: try [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) It will return the output as string so you can check whats going on.

Comment: Authentication issue? Your application may run under a different account than your terminal. Maybe try to specify explicit `-Credentials` in your command.

Comment: Likely differences between config in php-cli and php. look at your config to see if these methods are allowed.

Comment: @mPareek when i do it in the server command line, i got no output and the mail is correctly sent, but the same command run from th web page does nothing

Comment: Try this to debug: `exec('pwsh /data/web/html/myScript.ps 2>&1');` It should point out all the errors and also tell you info/details about the failed execution.

Comment: @marsze i'm sorry i don't know how to specify credentials, is this the smtp password? and can i run a command to know if the account/credentials used by my application is different than my terminal?

Comment: @PatricNox i got no result, is there a better way to debug than testing this command in a browser?

Comment: @PaulP I gave you the name of the parameter in my comment (`-Credential`), for more info see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7)